# Overriding error in a loop and asking the loop to assign a value of zero instead

Tags: r, loops, error-handling

I am calculating the percent overlap between pairs of animal home ranges, which are represented as sldf objects (Spatial Lines Data Frame). To do so, I created an empty vector, and then made a loop calculating the home ranges and the percent overlap before filling the empty vector with those overlap values.

Here is the last part of my loop:

```
  #Calculate percent overlap  

  base_area <- gArea(sldf)
  intersections<-gIntersection(sldf, sldf2)
  overlap<-gArea(intersections)/base_area
  

   Overlap[i]<-overlap #Place overlap value in empty vector
```

When there is no overlap between my two polygons, my loop stops and I get an error. This error is associated with the line of code

```
intersections<-gIntersection(sldf, sldf2)
```

The error is

```
 Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘is.projected’ for signature ‘"NULL"’
```

My issue is that some of my overlaps will necessarily be zero. This is not something I can change as it is part of my data.

I'm trying to find a way for my loop to override this error and place the value zero in my vector when this occurs. So far, I have tried the following as suggested in comments:

```
intersections <- try(gIntersection(sldf, sldf2), silent=T)
  if(is_null(intersections))
    intersections <- 0
```

However, this causes the next line of code (`overlap<-gArea(intersections)/base_area`) to crash because the function gArea is meant to handle spatial objects only, not numeric objects like zero. It returns the warning `Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : unable to find an inherited method for function ‘is.projected’ for signature ‘"numeric"’`.

I've also tried using the dplyr function if_else and purrr.possibly, but no luck. I get the same error. Any suggestions?

Comment: You could try `purrr::possibly()`.  It lets you set a default value if the function errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `try` from the `BBmisc` library with `is_null`, as follows:

```
intersections <- try(gIntersection(sldf, sldf2), silent=T)
if(is_null(intersections)){
   intersections <- 0
   overlap <- 0
}
else
   overlap <- gArea(intersections)/base_area
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I tried this and it did help, but created another error that caused the next line to crash. I'll edit the question to reflect this.

Comment: I see you've used `is_null` instead of `is.error`. Any reason?

Comment: Yes, when is.error was used, intersections remained a null variable and nothing changed. But if I used is_null, then intersections was changed to zero as I originally wanted.

Comment: The error you get now is because `gArea` doesn't accept zero as a parameter. So, you can also set `overlap` to zero as well to avoid this error. See my updated answer.